# python not returning value to node

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.7

node server code

```
let { PythonShell } = require("python-shell");

let options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.6\\python.exe',
    pythonOptions: ['-u'], 
    scriptPath: 'D:\\dev\\WebApps\\GeoMotLatest',
    args: ['WPLAN2019Q2', 'PRJ_NAME']
  };

pshell = PythonShell.run('hello.py', options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('results: %j', results.toString());
});
```

python script

```
 import sys
 def main():
     out = 'hello avi';

     print out
     return out
     sys.stdout.flush()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

hi

my node server code is calling python script and suppose to receive string back from python
for some reason i cant figure why nothing is received at the node end
all i get is null
help will be appreciated

Comment: `sys.stdout.flush()` will never be called and https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: hi thanks for responding  i deleted sys.stdout but still not working